# How to convert Date-time into Date using Netezza

Tags: sql, datetime, netezza

I am doing some calculation but my calculation is off because my date field is showing the time-stamp and i only want to use as Date only when i am doing the calculation.  How can i just ignore the minutes and just use the date when doing the calculation?  Here is what i have:

```
SELECT EF.DSCH_TS,
       CASE WHEN EXTRACT (DAY FROM  EF.DSCH_TS - EF.ADMT_TS)>=0 THEN 'GroupA' END AS CAL
FROM MainTable EF;
```

Answer (score 4):

Netezza has built-in function for this by simply using:

```
SELECT DATE(STATUS_DATE) AS DATE,
       COUNT(*) AS NUMBER_OF_             
FROM X
GROUP BY DATE(STATUS_DATE)
ORDER BY DATE(STATUS_DATE) ASC
```

This will return just the date portion of the timetamp and much more useful than casting it to a string with `TO_CHAR()` because it will work in `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`, and with other netezza date functions. (Where as the `TO_CHAR` method will not)

Also, the `DATE_TRUNC()` function will pull a specific value out of Timestamp ('Day', 'Month, 'Year', etc..) but not more than one of these without multiple functions and concatenate.

DATE() is the perfect and simple answer to this and I am surprised to see so many misleading answers to this question on Stack. I see `TO_DATE` a lot, which is Oracle's function for this but will not work on `Netezza`.

With your query, assuming that you're interested in the days between midnight to midnight of the two timestamps, it would look something like this:

```
SELECT EF.DSCH_TS,
  CASE
    WHEN EXTRACT (DAY FROM (DATE(EF.DSCH_TS) - DATE(EF.ADMT_TS)))>=0 THEN 'GroupA'
  END AS CAL
FROM MainTable EF;
```

Comment: @moe This should be marked as the answer to the question. Casting a timestamp to a date removes all of the time details of the field and is exactly what the title of the question is looking to do.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider rewriting your case statement to return an [interval](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ntz/v7r0m3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.nz.dbu.doc/r_dbuser_data_types_ntz_sql_interval_support.html).  This will allow for a little more flexibility.

```
        SELECT EF.DSCH_TS,
    CASE 
WHEN  age(date(EF.DSCH_TS),date(EF.ADMT_TS))>= interval '6 days' 
    THEN 'GroupA' END AS CAL
        FROM MainTable EF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `date_trunc()` with the first argument of `'day'`.  I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT EF.DSCH_TS,
       (case when date_trunc('day', EF.DSCH_TS) >= date_trunc('day', EF.ADMT_TS) THEN 'GroupA' END) AS CAL
FROM MainTable EF;
```

Comment: i am getting error: Function 'DATE_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP)' does not exist

Comment: @moe . . . I left the first argument out of the second call.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that worked but i am little bit confused about this function.  How would i modify if i want my condition to be like this: where EF.DSCH_TS > 6? because i want to test when number of days are greater than 0 or 1, 2,3 etc so i have a lot of case statement that i am not showing here. thanks for clarifying...

Comment: I think you would put the `date_trunc()` calls in the `extract(day from . . .)`.

Comment: how you do that can you please show me because i am not able to get it right.  thanks