# Delphi - How to identify end result address of URL redirection?

Tags: delphi, http

I have a web address that will take me to a different URL address.  This is MOST likely through a URL redirection.  I need a way of taking the initial URL and determining what the URL of the "end result" page would be.  I have looked around, and the Indy component TIdHTTP has been recommended.  Is this the best (aka simplest/easiest) way to do this?  As I have little experience with this type of coding, if anyone has sample code to share, it would be appreciated.

As an example, here is a starting URL that I have...

https://www.google.com/url?q=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392490/how-to-convert-date-time-into-date-using-netezza&ct=ga&cd=MTAwODU3OTM3OTYxNDU5ODk3Nw&cad=CAEYAA&usg=AFQjCNHTTseazfoavOyO68Kr8izCswpj_g

Thanks

Comment: Indy is OK for that. You have to issue HEAD or GET request and handle [redirection status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) until you get [success status](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest performing a simple get request and handling the OnRedirect event to save the last address that has been redirected to. You could also save intermediate addresses in case this is needed.

I wrote a small class to handle that, in the scope of your project you would probably add those methods to the class that needs the result though rather than encapsulating it.

```
  TRedirectTester = class
  private
    Address: string;
    procedure RedirectProc(Sender: TObject; var dest: string;
      var NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: boolean; var VMethod: TIdHTTPMethod);
  public
    function RedirectionResult(InitialURL: string): string;
  end;
```

I defined a public function to return the final URL after redirection and a private procedure to assign to the OnRedirect event (hence the signature) and a variable to store the redirection destination.

Regarding the implentation, remember setting `HandleRedirects` to `true` to enable the redirections, the `IOHandler` has to be assigned in order to be able to handle HTTPS. The method assigned to the `OnRedirect` event will be called every time a redirect occurs, so we can save the destination.

```
procedure TRedirectTester.RedirectProc(Sender: TObject; var dest: string;
  var NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: boolean; var VMethod: TIdHTTPMethod);
begin
  Address := dest;
end;

function TRedirectTester.RedirectionResult(InitialURL: string): string;
  var IdHttp: TIdHTTP;
begin
  Address := InitialURL;
  IdHttp := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    with IdHttp do
    begin
      HandleRedirects := true;
      OnRedirect := RedirectProc;
      IOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create;
      try
        Get(InitialURL);
      finally
        IOHandler.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    IdHttp.Free;
  end;
  Result := Address;
end;
```